# Цикл для создания 14 векторов в R

Tags: функции, циклы, r, вектор

**Всем привет! Пишу небольшой мультимассивный калькулятор в R под личные нужды:**

```
for (i in 1:27){
  if (x[i] == "PROFIT"){
    revenue[i] <-  plus[i]
  } else if (x[i] == "LOSS"){ 
    revenue_[i] <- minus[i]
  } else if (x[i] == "-"){
    revenue[i] <- 0
  } else {
    revenue[i] <- "ERROR"
  }}
```

Данный код исправен, на выходе выдает вектор, состоящий из 27 значений.
Следующим шагом мне необходимо умножить 1 значение в логике кода на вектор`vector_alpha`,состоящий из 14 значений.

```
 for (i in 1:27){
  if (x[i] == "PROFIT"){
    revenue[i] <-  plus[i]*vector_alpha
  } else if (x[i] == "LOSS"){ 
    revenue_[i] <- minus[i]
  } else if (x[i] == "-"){
    revenue[i] <- 0
  } else {
    revenue[i] <- "ERROR"
  }}
```

Таким образом, на выходе я хочу получить 14 векторов с 27 значениями. Не могу понять как правильно решить данную задачу, так как записывать ручным способом без автоматизации 14 пустых векторов для цикла неразумно, ведь при гипотетическом увеличении значений `vector_alpha` будет необходимо создание дополнительного количества пустых векторов ручным способом [чего хочется избежать]. Задачу пытался решить следующим образом:

```
 for (z in 1:14){
 answer_vector[z] <- for (i in 1:27){
  if (x[i] == "PROFIT"){
    revenue[i] <-  plus[i]*vector_alpha[z]
  } else if (x[i] == "LOSS"){ 
    revenue_[i] <- minus[i]
  } else if (x[i] == "-"){
    revenue[i] <- 0
  } else {
    revenue[i] <- "ERROR"
  }}}
```

R Studio выдавал ошибку следующего характера "replacement has length zero" + возникает всё тот же вопрос, как записать 14 вариантов векторов `answer_vector` без предварительного ручного создания пустых 14 векторов для записи ответа.
Все переменные в векторах количественные. Заранее благодарю всех, кто примет участие в решении данной задачи.

Comment: Для понимания полноты картины, покажите содержание вектора x

Answer (score 0):

```
# готовим данные 
# имеем вектор x из 27 элементов и от 1 до 27
x  <- 1:27
```

> результат
>
> ```
> > x
> # [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
> ```

```
# имеем вектор vector_alpha из 14-ти элементов, от 1 до 14
vector_alpha  <- 1:14
```

> результат
>
> ```
>  > vector_alpha
>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
> ```

```
# в результате на основании векторов vector_alpha и x необходимо получить  14 векторов длиной по 27 элементов
# по следующему алгоритму:
# Vector_alpha[1] * каждый элемент x[i] от 1 до 27 т. 1 *1, 1*2, 1*3 ... 1*27
# Vector_alpha[2] * каждый элемент x[i] от 1 до 27 т. 2 *1, 2*2, 2*3 ... 2*27
# Vector_alpha[3] * каждый элемент x[i] от 1 до 27 т. 3 *1, 3*2, 3*3 ... 3*27
#...
# Vector_alpha[14] * каждый элемент x[i] от 1 до 27 т. 14 *1, 14*2, 14*3 ... 14*27
#

# готовим результирующий набор векторов с используя список с помощью функции rep 
# размерностью 14 на 27
c  <- rep(list(rep(NA, length(x))), length(vector_alpha))
```

> ```
> > c
>
> [[1]]
> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>
> [[2]]
> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>
> [[3]]
> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
>
> ....
> [[14]]
> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> ```

```
# производим перемножение
for (i in 1:length(vector_alpha)) c[[i]]  <- vector_alpha[i]*x
```

> ```
> > c
>
> [[1]]
> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
>
> [[2]]
> [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 50 52 54
> ....
> [[14]]
> [1]  14  28  42  56  70  84  98 112 126 140 154 168 182 196 210 224 238 252 266 280 294 308 322 336 350 364 378
> ```